# How to get Twitter Bootstrap jQuery Elements (tooltip, popover, etc) working?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I've been playing with the Twitter Bootstrap test page in Dreamweaver and I absolutely can not get any sort of popover, tooltip, or other Bootstrap jQuery goodie to work. I've copied code from the demo page, poured over the source code, have direct links to all the correct JavaScript files, and still nothing. The CSS works fine though, just none of the animation.

The demo page mentions this code for something:

```
$('#example').popover(options)
```

But I have no idea what to do with something like that because I didn't see anything like that in any working site.

If anyone could give me any suggestions for the (probably) tiny link I'm missing, I'd greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT**

I found the following code snippet after posting this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel=popover]")
        .popover({
            offset: 10
        })
        .click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
        })
});
```

And it got the popovers triggering! I never saw anything like that in the source code of any of the working sites I saw though. Really wish the Bootstrap documentation could have made that tiny detail a bit clearer for new jQuery users like me.

Comment: Are you seeing any problems in the console? Perhaps that may give an indication of what is going wrong

Comment: Might also be a good idea to include the `<script>` declarations as they appear in your HTML source code.

Comment: If you're really new to jQuery and you're reading this, note two things: a) jQuery does not come with Twitter Bootstrap; you need to download it, and b) The examples they give use different paths to the js and CSS than you will use (and also include specific modules rather than just js/bootstrap.js), so be sure to edit the paths and js module names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify an id or class for the element you want to display a popover when it's hovered over. Here's an example:

```
<div id="example">Some element</div>

<script>
  $('#example').popover({
    title: 'A title!',
    content: 'Some content!' 
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Calvin! I just happened to find a similar snippet of code as you were responding. Wish the Bootstrap documentation could have made that just a touch more clear.

Comment: @KyleCarson, I agree, just had the same problem.

Answer (score 31):

For people coming here from Google:

You can get tooltip and popover to work automatically like the other Bootstrap plugins with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('body').popover({
            selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]'
        });

        $('body').tooltip({
            selector: 'a[rel="tooltip"], [data-toggle="tooltip"]'
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can then use data attributes like normal:

```
<a rel="tooltip" title="My tooltip">Link</a>
<a data-toggle="popover" data-content="test">Link</a>
<button data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="My tooltip">Button</button>
```

This is what the Bootstrap docs mean when it says that the data-api for these plugins are "opt in".

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue with the latest versions of Bootstrap: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7163. Please bump that issue on GitHub if you want it to get fixed, it's been sitting in the issue list for a long time now.

Comment: @vfcosta: that issue was fixed in the meantime. Can you please rm your comment? Thanks.

Comment: The [initialization code recommended by Bootstrap now](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) is different: `$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})`

Answer (score 0):

If you want bootstrap tooltip then:

```
    $(function () {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
    });
```

If you want Jquery tooltip then:

```
    /*** Handle jQuery plugin naming conflict between jQuery UI ***/
$.widget.bridge('uitooltip', $.ui.tooltip);

    $(function () {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").uitooltip();
    });
```

HTML will remain same in both the case:

```
  <div title="Tooltip text" rel="tooltip"> div data ... </div>
```